# Homebrew - dyld not found

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I run `brew` after a fresh install, and this is what I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
    Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    Reason: image not found
```

I've tried most of the common fixes. Everything is up to date, and I'm using 1.9.3. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error after installing rvm and then running brew on Mac OSX. It seems as if the brew script targets a System version of ruby in the script, which wasn't mounted by rvm. All that I did was change this line:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0
```

In my `/usr/local/bin/brew` file to this:

```
#!/Users/<my user name>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby -W0
```

The location that rvm installed the version of ruby I was using (NOTE: I omitted my username in the snippet above, the path should be to a valid install of ruby on your system)

brew started to be happy after that.